# How to get an array of an Element from an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, casting

I have an array of a struct, lets say

```cpp
struct cell{
  int pos;
  int id;
};

std::vector<cell> myArray;
```

I want an array of the `id` element. I can't just iterate over my array as it would take too long.

I have to provide `std::vector<int>` to a function.

My thought process was: Since arrays are usually just a pointer to the first element and then an offset I thought of creating an array where i can provide the offset, such as it would point to the `id` element of the next `cell` in `std::vector<cell> myArray`.

One solution I can think of is having an array of pointers to that element, for example:

The final solution might be something like:

```cpp
struct cell{
  int pos;
  int id;
};

std::vector<cell> myArray;
std::vector<int*> pointersToIds;

// Creating an array of int from an array of int*
std::vector<int> idsArray = std::something(pointersToIds);

myFunc(idsArray);
```

Since the std library has tons of stuff I supposed there would be a way to do this.

Is there a way to convert the array of pointers to an actual array of elements in a very optimized way? The pointers approach was the only i could think but it's doesn't necessarily have to be it.

Thank you all in advance :)

I tried iterating over the the array of pointers and creating an array of elements, but it would take too much time.

TLDR Get array of an element from array of struct

Comment: "*I tried iterating over the the array of pointers and creating an array of elements, but it would take too much time.*" Well, that's as efficient as it's going to get (outside of just iterating over the original array and building a new one without the pointer indirection).

Comment: "*I have to provide `std::vector<char>` to a function*" It's weird that this interface *specifically* takes a `vector<char>` rather than pointer and a size or two pointers or a span or something else. Is it going to manipulate the structure of this array in some way?

Comment: I used char as an example, but it take more of an array of ```int```, and no, it does not modify any of the elements or the structure it self.

Comment: I wanted to know if the std library offered anything that would kind of automatically create an vector of elements from an array of pointers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited to add more info

Comment: You claim you can't iterate over `myArray` as it would take too long.  How did you reach that conclusion?   Are there test results for realistic use cases demonstrating that is true?   If not, all you are doing is PREMATURE OPTMIZATION.

Comment: @Peter this array has to be updated and run at 60 times per second, and the array might contain a few million elements, maybe I can do this update in a multithreaded manner, but it would be much easier if I could just extract the contents from the array of pointers

Comment: It would take as much effort to build that array of pointers `std::vector<int*>`, as it would to just make `std::vector<int>` directly. Why do you want to do it in two steps instead of one? A one-liner would look [something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/5Wx639dd8)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The idea is creating the pointer vector `std::vector<int*>` beforehand, and passing it somehow as `std::vector<int>` to the function. The array is very big and I need low latency, therefore the solution you showed isn't viable.

Comment: If the function needs a `vector<int>`, then it needs a `vector<int>`. You can't magically fool it into taking a `vector<int*>` instead. And building a `vector<int>` from `vector<int*>` would take exactly as long as building `vector<int>` from `vector<cell>`. You've painted yourself into a corner; something's gotta give. Perhaps instead of `vector<cell>` you could store two separate vectors from the start, one for positions and one for IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this might be an instance of  [The XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), since it's not clear what you are actually trying to solve, do you:

1. Want to find a fast way to pass the list of struct to a function
2. Want a way to extract all the members from a list of struct into a list of members

First off, shoo away from your mind the idea of manually creating an array of addresses and then fiddling around with the offsets yourself, this is certainly *doable*, but probably hard to do yourself in a safe and portable way due to [Struct Alignment](https://carlosvin.github.io/langs/en/posts/cpp-pragma-pack/), something that differs from machine to machine.

besides accessing `cell.id` is already doing that in a portable way by itself!

### Problem 1.

If you want to pass a vector (or any object really) to a function in a fast way, you can use a **reference**, it would look something like this:

```cpp
void foo(std::vector<cell>& in_vec);
```

notice the `&` operator, declaring that `in_vec` must be passed as a reference, what this does internally is pass `in_vec` by address, avoiding copying values one by one, C++ does all this by himself and you can treat `in_vec` normally in the function without a care in the world, and it's blazing fast.

### Problem 2.

if your point is that you want to extract all the IDs before passing them to a function, first off, I still suggest you pass the cell, that way it is clear that `foo` is supposed to operate on cell IDs and not random integers, once again, paying the cost of unpacking the structs outside (which warrants an iteration) or inside (where you might not even need to access all cells depending on `foo`'s nature) is equal if not worse.

If you must carry through, it's as easy as a for loop:

```cpp
std::vector<int> ids;

for(auto const& cell : myArray)
{
    ids.push_back(cell.id); 
}
```

Or, if you want a elegant and modern solution, using lambdas and `algorithm`:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> ids;

std::transform(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), 
std::back_inserter(ids), [](cell const& c) {
    return c.id;
});
```

Or something to this effect.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone's answers made it clear that the way I was trying to approach the problem would not work. I fiddled with the API and made it accept a reference to the `std::vector<cell>`, but in the end I created a second array of only ids such as Tandetnik pointed out.